# Keras: getting augmentation parameters from ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to get values of rotation angles, height shift, width shift, and zoom values after the image being passed to [`ImageDataGenerator()`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/.), (not the range, but the random number from the data generator). However, I don't know how.

I'd looked at the Keras github and tried to get it from [the source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py)
but it didn't really worked out

The imported package in my code is:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing.image import array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
```

Comment: Can you specify what you would like to use this information for?, i.e. would you like to extract it during training? during testing? Or for tests? Or are you using this for something other non DNN related?

Comment: @ Xenon, I would like to use this information for Data Argumentation. Btw, Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: So during training? Usually you do not need that information for augmenting the data, because you do not want to tell your model how exactly you distorted the image as it is supposed to do it without knowing that information. I am arguing in this direction, because I think this usual case is why this is not implemented and thus doing it requires you to edit the source code there.

Comment: @Xenon I am using Data Augmentation for object detection. Since part object detection uses a lot of manual image tagging, so by augmenting the images, I want to know how many degree it rotate and how much it transforms in order to make a new tag location.

Comment: @Xenon It would be the best position to extract how much angle and how much it transform, so I can make new tags without doing it manually.